# How can I make a box with a constant size in Javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a grid-based 'drawing' game which has an area (a box) to draw in. In that box there are other boxes which u can draw (by changing their background-colors).
My question is, how can I make the main box (the drawing area) constant so that it won't resize if I change the size from 16x16 to 32x32 for example (and of course, the squares inside the area should scale to fit the new drawing area).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Etch a sketch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='main-container'>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
let size = 16;
mainContainer.style.display = 'grid';
mainContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = '1fr 1fr 1fr';
container.style.gridColumnStart = '2';
container.style.display = 'grid';
container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + size + ', 1fr)';
container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'auto';
container.style.gridAutoColumns = '30px';
container.style.gridAutoRows = '30px';

let element;
for(let i = 0; i < size*size; i++) {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element.textContent = '';
    element.onmouseenter = function() {
        console.log('over');
        element.style.background = 'black';
    };
    element.style.border = '1px solid black';
    container.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `gridTemplateColumns` a fixed pixel value.

`container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + size + ', 20px)';`

https://jsfiddle.net/tLy3147s/

**Edit:** If you want the drawing area to stay the same size and have the squares scale to fit, you'll need to calculate the size based on the number of squares you want.  Now, change `numSquares` and everything should adjust.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
const drawBox = 300;
const numSquares = 16;
let size = drawBox /  numSquares;

mainContainer.style.display = 'grid';
mainContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = '1fr 1fr 1fr';
container.style.gridColumnStart = '2';
container.style.width = drawBox + 'px';
container.style.display = 'grid';
container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + numSquares + ', auto)';
container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'auto';
container.style.gridAutoColumns = size + 'px';
container.style.gridAutoRows = size + 'px';

let element;
for(let i = 0; i < numSquares*numSquares; i++) {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element.textContent = '';
    element.onmouseenter = function() {
        console.log('over');
        element.style.background = 'black';
    };
    element.style.border = '1px solid black';
    container.appendChild(element);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v4gt2h3f/

Comment: The size of the main drawing area is still not constant.

Comment: @O.Joe I'm not understanding. You want the drawing area to stay the same size while fitting more of the same sized squares inside it?

Comment: @O.Joe Like, you have a grid of 16 x 16 squares. Let's say they're 10px each. So your drawing area would be 160 x 160. And you want to put 32 x 32 squares that are still 10px each into the same 160 x160 drawing area?

Comment: I want it like if the drawing area is 160x160, then resize the squares inside to fit the area

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix the size

```
container.style.width = '100px'
```

Comment: The problem is it's not gonna keep it's height, so for example if I set the size variable to be 32, it's going to make the cells inside higher with the same width size.